# How to add machine keys in GUIless server using Powershell for .net core applications

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, asp.net-core, iis

I have .Net core based applications hosted in MS azure on GUIless servers. I am using a load balancer as there are multiple servers.

I need to add same machinekey on both the GUIless server.

Can someone help me with the command to see and update machinekey on GUIless server using Powershell?

Appreciate help.

Comment: What is a "machinekey" and how do you usually deploy it on (GUI-having) servers?

Comment: Do you mean this? http://jeffgraves.me/2012/06/05/read-write-net-machine-key-with-powershell/

Comment: Are you trying to generate machine keys like this? https://www.niteshluharuka.com/generate-machinekey-using-windows-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

As Suggested by [Chaodeng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15570927/chaodeng) here is the PowerShell script for generating Machine key and also below are the few commands and steps on how to generate it.

1. You can save the below PowerShell script in your machine as `.ps1` file and this will help you in generating machine key

   ```
   # Generates a <machineKey> element that can be copied + pasted into a Web.config file.
        function Generate-MachineKey {
          [CmdletBinding()]
          param (
            [ValidateSet("AES", "DES", "3DES")]
            [string]$decryptionAlgorithm = 'AES',
            [ValidateSet("MD5", "SHA1", "HMACSHA256", "HMACSHA384", "HMACSHA512")]
            [string]$validationAlgorithm = 'HMACSHA256'
          )
          process {
            function BinaryToHex {
                [CmdLetBinding()]
                param($bytes)
                process {
                    $builder = new-object System.Text.StringBuilder
                    foreach ($b in $bytes) {
                      $builder = $builder.AppendFormat([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, "{0:X2}", $b)
                    }
                    $builder
                }
            }
            switch ($decryptionAlgorithm) {
              "AES" { $decryptionObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider }
              "DES" { $decryptionObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.DESCryptoServiceProvider }
              "3DES" { $decryptionObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider }
            }
            $decryptionObject.GenerateKey()
            $decryptionKey = BinaryToHex($decryptionObject.Key)
            $decryptionObject.Dispose()
            switch ($validationAlgorithm) {
              "MD5" { $validationObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACMD5 }
              "SHA1" { $validationObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1 }
              "HMACSHA256" { $validationObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 }
              "HMACSHA385" { $validationObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA384 }
              "HMACSHA512" { $validationObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512 }
            }
            $validationKey = BinaryToHex($validationObject.Key)
            $validationObject.Dispose()
            [string]::Format([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,
              "<machineKey decryption=`"{0}`" decryptionKey=`"{1}`" validation=`"{2}`" validationKey=`"{3}`" />",
              $decryptionAlgorithm.ToUpperInvariant(), $decryptionKey,
              $validationAlgorithm.ToUpperInvariant(), $validationKey)
          }
        }
   ```
2. Once you load the script in PowerShell using  `. . \(your.ps1file name)`, Now call the script by following command `Generate-MachineKey` which will make you generate the new machine key.

[image]